# How to orderBy a specified column in com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, querydsl

I have written JPA query for User entity as

```
public List<User> findActiveUsers(String sortColumn) {
    @Autowired
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    QUser user = QUser.user;

    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    builder.and(user.status.eq("ACTIVE"));

    JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(user)
                .where(builder);

    jpaQuery.offset(100);    
    jpaQuery.limit(20);
    //jpaQuery.orderBy([ORDER_SPECIFIER]);
    return jpaQuery.list(user);
}
```

I want to get the orderBy as a `String` parameter to the function and from that I want to build the `OrderSpecifier` as required in `jpaQuery.orderBy`.

Is there a way to do it like this?

```
 if(sortColumn ! null) {
     jpaQuery.orderBy(user.getColumn(sortColumn).asc());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a PathBuilder for your entity, that will allow to get the property path by name. Something like

```
if(sortColumn != null) {
    PathBuilder<User> userPathBuilder = new PathBuilder<User>(User.class, "user");
    jpaQuery.orderBy(new OrderSpecifier(Order.ASC, userPathBuilder.get(sortColumn)));
}
```